# How does one get timecode onto a 5d Mark IV from a Sound Devices MixPre-3 II?

Tags: input, timecode

I know how the audio recorder/mixer works.  It can send out timecode.  The question is, Can the Canon 5D Mark IV take that timecode in?

Sometimes a 3.5mm input can take in a timecode signal. Does that work on the 5D Mark IV?

Comment: Sometimes a 3.5mm input can take in a timecode signal.  Does that work on the 5D Mark IV?

Answer (score 1):

None of the Canon 5D series cameras will read incoming timecode. You can stripe it to one of the audio channels as a reference, but there is no camera timecode function as such.

Striping the timecode to camera audio will require your Video editing package to support LTC on audio tracks. I suspect that this is possible with Davinci Resolve.